# mongodb atlas M0 is slow at findAll for small collection

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I'm quite puzzled with mongodb atlas M0 behaviour.
I have a collection with 183 documents.

```
//  2 270 894
db.getCollection('MyColl').dataSize()

//  21 54 496
db.getCollection('MyColl').totalSize()


 db.getCollection("MyColl").find({}).limit(1000);
// 20 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 11 s 878 ms (execution: 402 ms, fetching: 11 s 476 ms)
```

Fetching should be high since I have poor internet connection.

Documents size in bytes

```
db.getCollection('MyColl').aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "name": 1,
      "object_size": { "$bsonSize": "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  {
   $sort : { object_size : -1 }
  }
])
```

```
159226
92179
74795
74548
73725
47848
45404
45271
```

so the most of documents are less than 45 kbytes.

Server metrics show that it takes around 25 seconds to fetch all 183 docs from mongo to server using spring-data-jpa.
Is there any explanation for it?

Anything weird thing is:
I have a non-unique index for field `{"lastSeenAt": 1}`

My Spring Repository has method

```
List<MyDoc> findAllByLastSeenAtIsNullOrLastSeenAtAfter(long ms);
```

it takes 25 seconds for `findAll`, it takes 35 seconds for `findAllByLastSeenAtIsNullOrLastSeenAtAfter` query that hits index.

Comment: M0 is a free tier cluster. Are you running into any of the [operational limits](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/free-shared-limitations/#operational-limitations) and being throttled?

Comment: @Capacytron why you're saying 20 rows retrieved? You have a limit of 1000, you fmust be fetching all docs in your collection, no?